# Add prefixed attribute in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, svg, elementtree, prefix

I am manipulating SVG files in ElementTree. Given the file `test.svg`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

I tried to create an element with specific prefix

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
tree = ET.parse('test.svg')
tree.getroot().set("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
link = ET.fromstring('<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/"></a>')
tree.write('worldMap/test_out.svg', encoding = 'utf-8', xml_declaration = True)
```

but run into a `unbound prefix` error. I've looked through [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721203629/http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm) but can't quite see what's wrong.

Comment: So whats the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `xlink` also in the string which you parse with `fromstring`:

```
link = ET.fromstring('<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" '
                     'xlink:href="http://www.mysite.com/"></a>')
```